# Tutorial for learning xaml for windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to develop mobile applications for the WINDOWS PHONE 7 using silverlight. Can anybody suggest me suitable tutorial please. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you should probably start at MSDN on the [Phone Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ff380145) section.

Then I would recommend you go and download the [Windows Phone 7 Developer Training Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wp7trainingcourse.aspx) which contains some introductory tutorials on getting started with WP7 and building your first app.

From there you can check out a couple of different things like the following:

1. This resource, [WP7 in 7 minutes](http://www.msdev.com/Directory/SeriesDescription.aspx?CourseId=158) was pretty helpful for accomplishing basic tasks when programming for WP7.
2. The [App Hup](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/) is a great spot for finding resources for developing for WP7 also (They have both Silverlight and XNA samples there).
3. This place, [Windows Phone 7 Tutorials - Kirupa.com](http://www.kirupa.com/windowsphone/index.htm) also has some pretty good tutorials.
4. [EugeneDOTNET](http://www.eugenedotnet.com/windows-phone-7/) has a ton of tutorials as well It's definetly worth checking out.

My last suggestion would be to follow Erno's suggestion and read the free [book](http://charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html) by Charles Petzold. That book is great for just getting started.

Keep in mind that most of these resources require you have a little experience in .NET and C#. If you want to learn that first check out this other [free book](http://www.robmiles.com/c-yellow-book/) by Rob Miles on learing C#.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your lengthy but clear answer. It cleared my doubts and helped me alot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

A lot depends on your experience.

If you know .NET get started with the free [book from Charles Petzold](http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/)

Comment: Thanks Erno. I am a beginner. I have started working on C# in the beginning of feb. I m now ok with C#. But cant understand where to start next.

Answer (score 2):

The [Windows Phone 7 for Absolute Beginners](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-7-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners) series on Channel 9 is an excellent way to get started.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the QuickStart guides in the app.hub at http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/quickstarts

also watch the JumStart training sessions on Channel9 http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/egibson/Windows-Phone-7-Jump-Start-Session-1-of-12-Introduction

Answer (score 1):

I used this ["Introduction to Windows Mobile 7 Development "](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/windows/introduction-to-windows-mobile-7-development/) when i first started.